# AWS Amplify Storage in S3 under AWS username and NOT identity_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have a web app where all of our users are referenced by their username, a uuid provided by AWS auth.

I'm having users store images in the s3 /protected/ folder.

By default the AWS amplify storage module puts files in

> protected/{user_identity_id}/

However, since all users are referenced by their username in my app and not by their user identity ID, I can't get the images of another user without also saving every users identity_id to their profile as well.

Is there a way to configure AWS amplify storage to store files in

> protected/{Username I define}/

instead?

Relevant docs are here but can't find anything about changing the default storage location

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#file-access-levels

Answer (score 0):

Also in the new docs there is no hint to choose a different id than the cognito id: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess?platform=js

If you put the access level to public you could concatenate the username into the filename e.g. {username}_image.png